# what is the role of <cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() >

Tags: opencv, face-recognition, lbph-algorithm

> i know that  cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() use it for recognize face in real time
> but i want to know what its fonction?,what exist inside this instruction ? how it is work?
> i want to know what itss struct for exemple it is take the image and extract caractrestic in forme lbph and its use for that .... than train image for that its use (name of trainer) compare the images  for can recognise them.
> any information or document can help me please pratge with me

Answer (score 0):

LBP(Local Binary Patterns) are one way to extract characteristic features of an object (Could be face, coffe cup or anything that has a representation). LBP's algorithm is really straight forward and can be done manually. (pixel thresholding + pixel level arithmetic operations.)

**LBP Algorithm:**

[image]

There is a "training" part in OpenCV's FaceRecognizer methods. Don't make this confuse you, there is no deep learning approach here. Just simple math.

OpenCV transforms LBP images to histograms to store spatial information of faces with the representation proposed by *Timo Ahonen, Abdenour Hadid, and Matti Pietikäinen. Face recognition with local binary patterns. In Computer vision-eccv 2004, pages 469–481. Springer, 2004.* . Which divides the LBP image to local regions sized *m* and extracting histogram for each region and concatenating them.

After having informations about one person's (1 label's) face, the rest is simple. During the inference, it calculates the test face's LBP, divides the regions and creates a histogram. Then compares its euclidian distance to the trained faces' histograms. If it's less than the tolerance value, it counts as a match. (Other distance methods can be used also, chi-squared distance absolute value etc. )